# Specify required fields and auto generated id field in Fluent API for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If I have a simple model such as this

```
public class Test
{
    [Key]
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public string TestRecord { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; } 
}
```

How do I specify in Fluent API that `TestId` needs to be autogenerated and incremented, and that `TestRecord` and `Type` are required fields?

This is what I have so far from googlin

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<T>().Property(t => t.TestRecord ).IsRequired();
 modelBuilder.Entity<T>().Property(t => t.Type ).IsRequired();
```

Is the above correct for ensuring required types ? Also how do I set up autoincrement ?

Answer (score 1):

Just do `modelBuilder.Entity<T>.HasKey(t => t.TestId);` for let the property auto generated and incremented.

IsRequired is correct to become the column required, the database must be create the column as non-nullable.